# orchestrate.io with nodejs get all records

Tags: node.js

I'm using nodejs and Orcestrate db. I would like to get all the records from a collection though i have much more than the limit. i found this :

```
db.list('address-book', {limit:10})
.then(function (page1) {
  // Got First Page
  if (page1.links && page1.links.next) {
    page1.links.next.get().then(function (page2) {
      // Got Second Page
    })
  }
})
.fail(function (err) {
})
```

But it wont help me because i don't really know how many pages i will have.
I'm getting confused with the recursive and nested callbacks.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I managed to create a recursive solution for this problem:

```
odb.list(collectionName, {limit:5})
        .then(function (page) {
            // Got First Page
            resArray=[];
            resArray.push(page.body.results);
            //make recursive call fir fetching new pages
            recSearch(page,resArray,callback)

        })
        .fail(function (err) {

        })


function recSearch(page, resArray, callback){
//check if there is more pages
    if (page.links && page.links.next) {
        page.links.next.get().then(function (page2) {
            //push another page result to the array
            resArray.push(page2.body.results);
            recSearch(page2,resArray,callback)//recursice call for next page
        })
    }else{
    //case there is no more pages to go, put all values in one array
    //and callback the original function    
        var valuesArray = new Array;
        for (var onePage in resArray){
            for (var o in resArray[onePage]){
                valuesArray.push(resArray[onePage][o].value;
            }
        }
        callback(null,valuesArray);
    }

}
```